# Custom scope not returning any results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, associations, factory-bot

Basic association setup (note, Customer is an extension of a Person model):

```
Customer has_many :orders
Order belongs_to :customer
```

Inside of Customer.rb, I have the following class method:

```
# SCOPE
def self.ordered_in_90_days
  joins(:orders).where('orders.created_at > ?', 90.days.ago)
end
```

In my test, I have the following code which creates a new Order (automatically creating a customer thanks for FactoryGirl), then uses the Customer model's self method defined above:

```
it "finds customers who have ordered within the last 90 days" do
  @order     = FactoryGirl.create(:order, created_at: 50.days.ago)
  @customer  = @order.customer

  Customer.count.should == 1  #passes
  Order.count.should == 1     #passes

  puts Customer.all.to_yaml   #for debugging, see below
  puts Order.all.to_yaml      #for debugging, see below

  Customer.ordered_in_90_days.should == [@customer]   #fails! returns: []
end
```

Both the customer and order are being created, but nothing is returning in the method call (empty array). What am I missing?

Here is some additional information regarding the factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :customer do
        first_name "Wes"
        last_name "Foster"
        type "Customer"
    end

    factory :order do
        customer
    end
end
```

And here is the debugging output for Customer and Order (remember, Customer is an extension of Person, so that's why you see person_id instead of customer_id):

```
---
- !ruby/object:Customer
  attributes:
    id: 1
    first_name: Wes
    last_name: Foster
    type: Customer
    created_at: 2013-09-16 21:54:26.162851000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-09-16 21:54:26.162851000 Z
    middle_name: 
---
- !ruby/object:Order
  attributes:
    id: 1
    person_id: 
    created_at: 2013-07-28 21:54:26.135748000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-09-16 21:54:26.192877000 Z
```

(Customer

Comment: Try putting a debugger statement at the beginning of that test example, then run through the test and inspect all the related objects to make sure their attributes are exactly as you expect. Are you sure you're getting the exactly right order, customer, and created_at?

Comment: Also, maybe post your factory for Order so we can see that code.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your class method/scope: I tried a similar scope against some models in one of my apps and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I've added factory and debug information. Hopefully you can see something I cannot :)

Comment: Great, take a look at my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug output indicates the problem, indeed! Take a look at the Order inspect: you have person_id blank.

First, even if a Customer is a subclass/extension of Person, the Order `belongs_to :customer` tells ActiveRecord to look for `customer_id`, not `person_id`. Are you indicating that the association should be configured in a non-default way on the Order model?

Otherwise, I think you might be mishandling the aliased association reference in the Order factory. I've not used factory_girl association alias references in my project—I try to keep associations out of my factories—but I would verify your methodology with the factory_girl documentation: [Association Aliases](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#aliases).

I would, personally, try this in your test example:

```
it "finds customers who have ordered within the last 90 days" do
  @customer  = FactoryGirl.create(:customer)
  @order     = FactoryGirl.create(:order, created_at: 50.days.ago, customer: @customer)

  Customer.count.should == 1  
  Order.count.should == 1     

  Customer.ordered_in_90_days.should == [@customer]
end
```

Setting the @order.customer explicitly in your examples allows you to eliminate the factory dependency and complexity.

**Sidenote**
If you want to keep the association alias method in your factory, and rely on that association in other tests, I would suggest writing a separate test to verify that factory relationship instantiating correctly:

```
@order = create(:order)
expect(@order.customer).to be_a(Customer)
```

Or something like that...

Comment: Thanks Carlos. Yes, I had the `foreign_key` attribute assigned for both the Order and Customer models. The problem seems to be with FactoryGirl not associating the Order and Customer when the order is being creating. I can't believe I missed that in the yaml! You pointed me in the right direction, and I've reordered the creation of my order and customer like you suggested. Everything seems to be running smoothly now. And thanks for the tip on the order/customer association test. Lastly, FactoryGirl aliases aren't necessary in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad I could help! I appreciated the chance to refresh my FactoryGirl knowledge.